# Is there any way to sending user defined unique key in request to SMSC and getting it back in delivery report message?

Tags: python, smpp

Currently I am working on SMS GW. I would like to know the following things :

1. When you pass extra optional parameters through SUBMIT_SM, is there any setting needs to be done at SMPP side.
   How to get extra optional parameters)being sent in request from client) in the delivery message string(mesage id, done date, dlvrd, err code etc)
2. How to pass a unique key while submtiting message so that when the delivery report message comes, you can fetch that key and one/more parameters from the delivery message string and update it in database?
3. What is difference between SUBMIT_SM, DATA_SM and DELIVER_SM?
4. Is there any way where i can customize the text in delivery message .Normally part of outgoing message is displayed. Can i get full message or specific part of message from SMSC?

Thanks,
Varun